# C# Main Form Reference Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, reference

i made an UserControl and wanted to add the MainForm Reference

```
  public partial class ConsolePage : UserControl
{
    public synForm mainForm = new synForm();

    public ConsolePage(synForm parentForm)
    {
        mainForm = parentForm();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

so, the thing is that as Long i create my UserControl in c# code (doesnt matter where) it works perfectly but when i try to add him from my Designer from Toolbox then im getting an exception.

I know, that i should call them like this

```
MyControl whatever = new MyControl(this);
```

and i know that i should correct that in my Form.Designer if i want to add myControl from Toolbox!

Dont hate me im new in programming and spelling :D

EDIT : <<<<<<<

Forgot to put what error i got :

```
System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)

System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)

System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, Object[] parameters, String name, Boolean addToContainer)

System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.ComponentCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, Object[] parameters, String name, Boolean addToContainer)

System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)

System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.DeserializeStatementToInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
 System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
bei System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)

System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeName(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeStatementCollection statements)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us what exception you are getting and illustrated the problem better.

Comment: This can't be your real code as `parentForm()` would not work.

Comment: Why do `public synForm mainForm = new synForm();`? Isn't `private synForm mainForm;` better in your case?

Comment: The "error" you put looks like the stacktrace with no actual exception.

Comment: You have a parameter on the constructor so you can't use the designer. You have to create the control using code.

Comment: Delete your implementation of parent form parameter and just use this in your user control: `Form thisIsYourParentForm = (this.Parent as Form);`. And don't forget to null check `thisIsYourParentForm.`

Comment: `I wanted to make it easier to understand` It is crucial that the code you show us - a) compiles b) has the same bug / behaviour as your real code.

Comment: Please don't accept an answer that can't possibly produce legal code nor solve your problem.

Comment: @Enigmativity why should i not  accept an answer when it helped me?

Comment: @Guardian - How could it help if it doesn't even compile? Even if it did compile it wouldn't give you the functionality you wanted. You wanted a reference to parent form passed in - this doesn't do that.

Comment: @Enigmativity again , im wondering either :D but it Shows me what i wanted to see.

Comment: @Guardian - Yes, but the primary purpose of this site is to create a library of quality questions and answers for future readers. It is only a secondary to this that the asker of the question gets an answer that they like. It's the responsibility of every user to try to help to achieve the primary goal. Hence why I'm asking you not to accept this answer. It doesn't help future readers. In fact, it's detrimental to them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without knowing the error message (you provided only the stack trace) and content of parentForm() it is not that easy to say. But it seems parentForm() is doning something that is not possible in the designer.

So you could try to not execute parentForm() in design mode by checking DesignMode (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component.designmode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ComponentModel_Component_DesignMode).

```
public ConsolePage()
    {
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            mainForm = parentForm();
        }
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: How can this possibly be correct? If `parentForm` is of type `synForm` then it is impossible to execute it with `parentForm` and then assign it back as `synForm`.

Comment: Well, that helped me, i dont really know how, but it works!

Comment: I expect parentForm is a method that return synForm, and due to the error description it seams not working in design mode. Without haveing more code I can not say more